# How build startLocation path in alfresco?

Tags: java, alfresco

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119393/is-it-possible-to-make-document-picker-default-to-document-library-in-alfresco-s) and [here](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/187930-association-control-and-startlocation) example of `startLocation`:

```
/app:company_home/app:dictionary 
/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:acme
```

Let say that I have opened repository in browser (!) and go to `Repository/Data Dictionary/Imap Configs/Templates` (or any other path). The name in the path is what I see in repository browser.

How to calculate `startLocation` from that path? (E.g. `xxx:repository/yy:data_dictionary:zz:imap_config`)

It does not actually matter what concrete path is, it is needed to know what the algorithm about "generating" `startLocation` path.

Comment: What format do you have the path in that you want to use? Name? QName? NodeRef? Other?

Answer (score 0):

- Alfresco script:

  ```
  var browserPath = "/Data Dictionary/Imap Configs/Templates";
  var scriptNode = companyhome.childByNamePath(browserPath);

  logger.info(scriptNode.qnamePath); 
  // /app:company_home/app:dictionary/app:imap_configs/app:imap_templates

  logger.info(scriptNode.displayPath+"/"+scriptNode.name); 
  // /Company Home/Data Dictionary/Imap Configs/Templates

  logger.info(scriptNode.nodeRef); 
  // workspace://SpacesStore/a9eef6dc-c20b-4be8-a9eb-807c9505c61e

  logger.info(scriptNode.id); 
  // a9eef6dc-c20b-4be8-a9eb-807c9505c61e

  logger.info(scriptNode.url); 
  // /n/browse/workspace/SpacesStore/a9eef6dc-c20b-4be8-a9eb-807c9505c61e

  logger.info(scriptNode.webdavUrl); 
  // /webdav/Data%20Dictionary/Imap%20Configs/Templates
  ```
- Alfresco CMIS/REST API:

  [/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/root/**Data Dictionary/Imap Configs/Templates/**?cmisselector=object&succinct=true](http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/root/Data%20Dictionary/Imap%20Configs/Templates/?cmisselector=object&succinct=true)

  ```
  {
      "succinctProperties": {
          "cmis:objectId": "a9eef6dc-c20b-4be8-a9eb-807c9505c61e",
          "alfcmis:nodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/a9eef6dc-c20b-4be8-a9eb-807c9505c61e",
          "cmis:path": "/Data Dictionary/Imap Configs/Templates",
          "cmis:name": "Templates",
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The path for `startLocation`, which is used in `packageitems.ftl` can be calculate with alfresco admin console. You should go to `/alfresco/s/admin/admin-nodebrowser`. Select `workspace://SpacesStore` as storage, and `selectnodes` in drop down list as "left part" of request. Then type `/app:company_home`, click the button and click on `name` column in the table result. After that You will see the following:

- `Primary Path` - corresonds to path in `startLocation`
- `Children` - nested "folders" and "files"
- `cm:name` - the property which is used when you traverse folders in repository.

So should start from `/app:company_home` first, then select child from `Children` look at `cm:name` to determine that you at right way and select children until you get needed location. Then simple copy `Primary Path` into `startLocation` and controll element opens where you need. Like that:

```
/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:mySite/cm:dataLists/cm:Companies
```